# Para que serve a estrutura "PyObject" e quais são os objetivos de seus membros?

Tags: python, python-internals, cpython

Estou analisando a estrutura [PyObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h#L109) do [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython). O código para esta estrutura segue abaixo.

**Estrutura `PyObject`**:

```c
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas em relação aos membros desta estrutura, mais especificamente o membro `_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` que não deu para entender muito bem qual é a finalidade dele para a estrutura.

## Dúvidas

1. Para que serve a estrutura `PyObject`?
2. Qual é o objetivo de cada membro da estrutura `PyObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta estrutura é uma implementação do sistema de objetos da linguagem python - cada instância de qualquer objeto do python é armazenada em uma estrutura dessas. Existem duas. A `PyObject` que você mostrou acima e a `PyVarObject` que é para objetos com tamanho variável.

Vamos aos membros:

Essa `_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` é uma macro, segue abaixo a definição dela:

```
#define _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA            \
    struct _object *_ob_next;           \
    struct _object *_ob_prev;
```

Ela é usada para colocar ponteiros para o próximo objeto e o anterior, efetivamente definindo uma lista dinâmica de vínculo duplo que engloba todos os objetos. Essa definição está protegida por um `#ifdef` e só é ativada em casos específicos de debugagem: Quando os desenvolvedores do `CPython` estão procurando algum problema na alocação de objetos, eles ativam essa função para poder percorrer os objetos na memória e encontrar o problema. Mas normalmente ela se encontra desabilitada, e `_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` **não faz nada**.

Continuando, `ob_refcnt` é o número de referências ao objeto e `ob_type` é uma referência a um outro objeto que representa o **tipo** deste objeto. Geralmente é uma classe.